# set status code inside a ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, http

I am working on a web service with some existing code in Java. The web service uses the ServletResponse interface to generate the response. The current code create the ServletResponse object first, set the headers, then pass a ServletOutputStream to another method, and let the other method to write the response body part. Code as below:

```
{
   ServeletResponse sr = new HttpServletResponseWrapper();
   sr.setContentType("text/xml;charset=utf-8");
//checkLogic write the HTTP response body to outputstream
   checkLogic(xmlRequestTree, sr.getOutputStream());
}
```

'checkLogic' checks the validation of xmlRequestTree(regarding to our bussiness logic), and if validated, write the response to the passed outputstream, if not, write an error to the outputstream. Now I would like to change the checkLogic(), when validations fails, not only write a error message but also return a HTTP error code. My question is, if keep the current code structure unchanged, is it possible to set the HTTP code inside checkLogic(), as checkLogic() only get a OutPutStream of the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need the ServletResponse object.